# Xcode Crash NO_CRASH_STACK + 0 with no stack trace and unsymbolicated

Tags: xcode, xcode-organizer

Can anyone tell me what is this crash about since there's no stack trace and cannot be symbolicated?

I'll paste here only the relevant part of the crash. My project is written in Swift.

```
NO_CRASH_STACK + 0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000102445424
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [18568]
Triggered by Thread:  7

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x282ced140 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   ------------                    0x0000000102445424 0x102304000 + 1315876
1   ------------                    0x0000000102444a9c 0x102304000 + 1313436
2   ------------                    0x000000010232e408 0x102304000 + 173064
3   ------------                    0x000000010232b320 0x102304000 + 160544
4   CFNetwork                       0x0000000208b5b228 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000208b6f9c8 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 176
6   Foundation                      0x000000020900e82c __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
7   Foundation                      0x0000000208f16a28 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x0000000208f15efc -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740
9   Foundation                      0x0000000209010700 __NSOQSchedule_f + 272
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207fb96c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207fba484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207f5d83c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207f5cf04 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207f69a28 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000207f6a2d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020819c17c _pthread_wqthread + 472
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020819ecec start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself just by downloading the dSYM files from App Store Connect and Xcode automatically symbolicated the crash.